# Displaying a menu child in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, menu

How to make a child menu visible in Drupal 7 ?

The child menu appears just when I inter to the page of the parent menu. I want to make it visible whenever i put the mouse on the parent menu.

I hope it's clear!

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer :

Go to your parent menu item, edit it and click on the 'Show as expanded' checkbox. Now all the children menu items should be visible from the top level.